# Make post request with separate hostname and url in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to make a request.post(someURL) where the host name is not the same as the url.

The host I am trying to reach is in a private cluster but is accessible from a public URL. The problem is when I make a normal post request I get a 404 response because the host is expecting its internal name (hostName).

Is there a way to do something like response = request.post(someURL, hostname = hostName, data = data) so the request will go to someURL but give hostName as the host name instead of someURL.

Comment: Used Host field in the header and that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"hosts" are almost always passed in the header. try something like this

```
#add/remove whatever other headers you need
headers={
    'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Host':'hostName'
}

response = request.post(someURL, headers=headers, data = data)
```

Note you may want to check the request as some sites require a Host, Origin, Referer, etc.